# JavaFX deploy info is not shown in EXE file

Tags: java, ant, javafx

I'm creating the Setup EXE sucessfuly with  and InnoSetup.
What I cannot see is that the properties of the self contained exe (the small Jar-wrapper-exe) file are populated, i.e., after installation, go to install dir, right-click in the exe file of the application, and go to properties-details: product name, product versión, copyright, etc are not populated.

The FX ant task explicitly set the values:

```
<fx:deploy ...>
<fx:info 
     title="${application.title}" 
     vendor="${application.vendor}" 
     copyright="${application.vendor}">
</fx:info>
</fx:deploy>
```

and the variables were set:

```
<property name="application.title" value="TheApp"/>
<property name="application.vendor" value="TheVendor"/>
```

Does anyone knows why? Or is it that the fx:info information will only be written to the setup exe file (the one that comes out of Inno Setup, this is actually happening).

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does the `exe` created by you ant script (without the inno setup) has the properties mentioned by you?

Comment: Hi @ItachiUchiha, the application is build using the autogenerated build.xml of JavaFX. That means that the jar compiling, deploy step and InnoSetup step execute one after the other. I just populate "my values" but the overall process is the default JFX build of the self contained exe. Hence I don't have control (or don't know how to) in the exe creation (this one is created in the User/Temp directory)